# SOAP-Request with Vector, Cast-Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, soap, ksoap2

I've a problem with a SOAP request to a PHP-SOAP-Webservice with Java (with Android SDK)
I have a SOAP-Helper class. This class connects to the SOAP-Service and get all raw-data from the server.
In this class i've implemented the following method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static Vector<SoapObject> getLayers(){
    try {
        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.XYZ.ch/YYY/webservice.php/getLayers";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "getLayers";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);

        Vector<SoapObject> result = (Vector<SoapObject>)soapEnvelope.getResponse();

        return result;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then I have a class which gets the data from the helper-class. here is the class for the layers.

```
public void getLayers(){
    Vector<SoapObject> vectorLayers = SOAPHelper.getLayers();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

    for(int i=0; i<vectorLayers.size(); i++){                               
        HashMap<String, Object> layers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        layers.put("layerId", vectorLayers.get(i).getProperty(0));
        layers.put("layerName", vectorLayers.get(i).getProperty(1));
        myList.add(layers);
    }
}
```

Now I have this cast error:

```
05-02 13:11:56.866: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(988): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Vector
```

With the debugger, i see all data in the Vector. The vector isn't empty. All data are correct.

Any ideas?

Thank you
rob

Comment: Can you show a full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely object returned from `soapEnvelope.getResponse()` is not a `Vector`. Try just using `Collection<SoapObject>`.